# Function f(1/n)=1/n!

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to work on a problem in complex analysis. Although I know how to solve it, I am only stuck at one point.

The problem asks if there exist a holomorphic function $f$ on the unit disk such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n!}$.

Here, the approach will be to consider another function $g$ that coincides with $f$ on a discrete set (mainly $\{\frac{1}{n};n \in \mathbb{N}$}) and use the uniqueness theorem to show that they coincide with each other everywhere on the unit ball.

Now, if our function $g$ is not analytic on the unit ball, we will get what we need.

I cannot find such function $g$. It is easy to do it when $f(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}$ but here the factorial is making it a little bit difficult.

Comment: Do you know a complex function that extends the positive integers factorial? I'm thinking $f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}$

Comment: I do not. I can read about it. It is not analytic on the u it disk?

Comment: Related: [holomorphic function on punctured disk satisfying $\left|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{n!}$ has an essential singularity at $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104353/holomorphic-function-on-punctured-disk-satisfying-leftf-left-frac1n-righ)

Comment: Your logic seems flawed to me: if $g$ is not analytic, then you have no reason to claim that it coincides with $f$ on the unit ball. For instance, you could just define $g(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n!}$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x$ is not the reciprocal of a positive integer; but it is clear that this proves nothing.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right. I think this would have worked if f analytic on a bigger disk and we only need them to coincide on the smaller one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such function. If there was, its Taylor series centered at $0$ would be of the form$$a_kz^k+a_{k+1}z^{k+1}+\cdots,$$for some $k\in\mathbb N$ and $a_k\neq0$. But then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lvert f\left(\frac1n\right)\right\rvert}{\left\lvert\frac{a_k}{n^k}\right\rvert}=1.$$In particular$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lvert f\left(\frac1n\right)\right\rvert}{\frac1{n^k}}\neq0.$$But$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{n!}}{\frac1{n^k}}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you. Both answers make sense. Do you think there is an approach using the uniqueness theorem without going through the gamma function?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 9):

The idea is simply that such a function, to exist, would have to be "too flat". More formally: let $f$ be an hypotetical holomorphic function that satisfies your hypothesis. It would then satisty:

$$f(0)=\lim f(\frac 1n)=\lim \frac 1{n!}=0\\
f'(0)=\lim \frac{f(\frac 1n)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim \frac{n}{n!}=0\\
f^{(k)}=k!\lim \frac{f(\frac 1n)}{n^k}=k!\lim \frac{n^k}{n!}=0
$$

Thus $f=\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(0)z^n}{n!}=0$, which contradicts $f(\frac 1n)=\frac 1{n!}$